# Does Dask guarantee that rows inside partition (with a non-unique index) will never be reordered?

Tags: python, pandas, dask

My application needs to read in a dataset into dask, spread across multiple partitions. With that dataframe, I need to do multiple operations on it, (eg subtracting one column from another or finding the ratio of two columns). The index for the dataframe is a nonunique column.

Because the application is entirely metadata driven, the order of the function calls is not known until runtime, so I have designed the application to rely on returning a new delayed dataframe at each stage.  I wondered if some clever use of partitioning and column-wise concatenation could help me make this code efficient.

Given that these steps are independent of each other, in the specific example below can I trust the last operation to give the proper result for my row-wise ratio? i.e. If I carry out operations that only add new columns to dataframes, can I trust that the ordering of the rows will never change?

```
def subtract(df1, df2, col1, col2):
  df_mod = copy(df1)
  df_mod[f"{col1}-{col2}"] = df1[col1] - df2[col2]
  return df_mod


def ratio(df1, df2, col1, col2):
  df_mod = copy(df1)

  # Rely on the row ordering being unchanged
  df_mod[f"{col1}/{col2}"] = df1[col1] / df2[col2]
  return df_mod

df = load_function_returns_dask_df()


first = subtract(df, df, "a","b")
second = subtract(df, df, "c","d")

last = ratio(first, second, "a-b","c-d")
```

I understand that I could operate directly on the dataframe to create a new column, but this does not work in the general case for arbitrary operations.

Intuitively it makes sense to me that this operation should work, since each partition is just a pandas dataframe, and it makes no sense for pandas to reorder the rows in a dataframe arbitrarily, but I was hoping for some way of verifying this more formally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct, Dask will not reorder your partition rows so long as you are doing Pandas operations which themselves do not ordinarily reorder the rows (such as `sort`, obviously), which will be true for any row-wise computation.

Indeed the order of the partitions themselves is preserved as the data passes through operation after operation.